# How to ignore or include specific metrics in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

I heard about ignore_metrics configuration item which can be used to ignore or include specific Prometheus metrics, but cannot find any official documentation how to use it. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Adding a scrape config target will includes its metrics. To (temporarily) exclude metrics, see: https://www.robustperception.io/dropping-metrics-at-scrape-time-with-prometheus

Comment: Thanks, @DazWiikin. What do you mean by temporarily exclude? Won't they be excluded permanently?

Comment: Once you remove the respective config they will appear again. This is what he meant I assume

Comment: Correct. Plus the metrics continue to be exported, the client is just choosing to ignore them. So, per the post, if these are redundant or noisy, a better solution is to stop them being produced.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `metric_relabel_configs` to filter out already scraped values. So, when you exclude any metric this way it will not be stored in db, using this approach you can reduce disk usage and exclude all not necessary metrics. e.g.:

```
metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [ __name__ ]
    regex: 'istio_.*'
    action: drop
```

in this example all metrics which name starts with  `istio_` will not be stored.

Answer (score 1):

To filer out

```
transformations:
      - description: "General processing rules"
        ignore_metrics:
          - prefixes:
            - "go_"
            - "process_"
```

To ignore the go_ and process_ metrics

```
go_goroutines 13
process_virtual_memory_bytes 2.062336e+07
mysql_global_status_commands_total{command="ha_close"} 0
mysql_global_status_commands_total{command="ha_open"} 0
```

Example from

[https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/prometheus-integrations/install-configure-openmetrics/ignore-or-include-prometheus-metrics/#:~:text=To%20filter%20out%20unwanted%20metrics,use%20the%20scrape_enabled_label%20configuration%20option](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/prometheus-integrations/install-configure-openmetrics/ignore-or-include-prometheus-metrics/#:%7E:text=To%20filter%20out%20unwanted%20metrics,use%20the%20scrape_enabled_label%20configuration%20option).